# Responsive site not working on mobile

Tags: html, css, mobile, responsive-design

I have made a responsive site which collapses fine when in a browser window but when used on a mobile it displays the full site?

Is there anything anyone can spot in my code which would be causing this?

Please find a hosted site below

http://onlyukdating.com/daily-breeze/

and I'm linking my style sheets via by using this mark up in my head tag

Thanks

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link 
to the site that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value
to future visitors once the problem is solved. Posting a 
[Short, Self Contained, Correct Example (SSCCE)](http://www.sscce.org/) 
that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, 
see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to
it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Add this to the head of your docuemnt

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

From MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag

Answer (score 1):

@Iharby answer is correct, but If you want to sleep well I think you should add a little bit more:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
```

Comment: don't know why but this worked while the other answer ( which is given everywhere didn't work for me )